# Selecting records in SDE using table join in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I am in the process of writing an Arc Tool that will create a point feature class in SDE from field data. The incoming data already has a UUID (in field [UID]) that is brought over with the incoming data. There will be existing records in the SDE feature class that I will want to flag for QA/QC by setting a field value [QAQC_FLAG]=1. Seems simple enough. Right?

Nope.

I am trying to use a table join and select to select records in the existing feature class that have identical UUID values in the incoming field data. My current code looks like this.

```
    joinField = "UID"
    updField = "QAQC_FLAG"
    joinSel = '''ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".AquaDat_MidReachPts.UID = ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".tempPts.UID'''
    arcpy.JoinField_management(tempPtFC,joinField,outFC,joinField,updField)
    edit.startEditing("False", "True") #Start edit session
    edit.startOperation()
    updateCursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFC, updField, joinSel)
    for rec in updateCursor:
        updField = 1
```

Seems like this should work, but it doesn't (obviously). The code falls on its face when it tries to execute the joinSel statement and returns this error message:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kgaines\Documents\Aquadat\Scripting\AquaDat_FC_CreateMidPts_ArcTool_tableJoin.py", line 150, in 
    for rec in updateCursor:
RuntimeError: Attribute column not found [42000:[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "ilmocbpj.BLM\KGAINES.tempPts.UID" could not be bound.] [ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".AquaDat_MidReachPts]*

I keep thinking that the format/encapsulation of the joinSel statement is the problem. I have manipulated the single and double quotes until I can't think of anymore ways to manipulate them.

The UID field exists as shown here:
[image: AquaDat Table Properties]

I am working in ArcGIS 10.3.1 with ArcSDE in a SQL Server database instance. The ArcPy script does register the newly created feature classes as versioned with SDE if it has to create them.

Comment: JoinField adds a field to the table, does not create a join.  You do not need to fully qualify the field name in the query if the table is not joined,

Comment: I tried arcpy.AddJoin_management and got nowhere with it.

Comment: I recommend you run your script up to and including the JoinField line, then open the feature class in ArcMap and use the "Selet By Attribute" tool to validate your query, that is what you will want to use for the joinSel variable...

Comment: Same error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
    for rec in updateCursor:
RuntimeError: Attribute column not found [42000:[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "ilmocbpj.BLM\KGAINES.tempPts.UID" could not be bound.] [ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".AquaDat_MidReachPts]

Failed to execute (AquaDatIngest).

Here is the new joinSel statement that I used after creating the join and select statement in ArcMap:

        joinSel = 'ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".AquaDat_MidReachPts.UID = ilmocbpj."BLM\KGAINES".tempPts.UID'

Comment: Use the wizard to construct your query...

Comment: Do I even need the join with the update cursor?

Comment: Data is *never* stored "in SDE"; though it may be stored in a "SQL Server 20xx R*y* enterprise geodatabase through an ArcSDE connection".  Naming your UUID column "uid" is confusing, as is making it a string type. I generally use SQL to define my table columns, to make sure they manifest in the correct type.

Comment: Make sure you escape backslashes in Python strings or use the "raw" formatting tag.

Comment: The problem I run into here is that I have a table of incoming data with pre-populated UUIDs. These are what I want to use as a check for duplicated records to set [QAQC_FLAG] = 1 so that the end users can go back into the data to verify site revisits or duplicated records from the incoming datasets. If I make the UUID column into a type 'Guid' in SDE, the incoming records are given a new ID on ingestion.